# How to design and develop a web page in asp.net using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using VB.NET AND ASP.NET

Am new to web design and development, I want to know how to design and develop a web page using vb.net and asp.net.

I need a link of samples and help sites for developing a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.asp.net/ -- lots of good examples, videos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered picking up a book? I recommend [Begining ASP.NET 3.5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047018759X) that I'm currently reading... this book does a good job of getting you started with ASP.NET development. The code samples are in both VB and C#.